# Creating a separate excel file for each filter result

Tags: excel, file, vba, filtering

I have a spreadsheet which I want to split to separate spreadsheets for each department there are more then the departments shown and I want the .xls files for each to be save with the department name

The department field is column D.

i.e. I would like an .xls file for each with only the records for department 1, department 2, and so on.

Unfortunately I am unable to post a screenshot of the spreadsheet as my rep isn't good enough yet.

What VBA code would I use to do this?

Comment: Excel 2003. (response in comments section of Daniel's answer)

Answer (score 2):

This should do what you need. If you run it and provide a column letter it will base it on that column, otherwise it'll default to D as you specified:

```
Sub SplitWorkbook(Optional colLetter As String, Optional SavePath As String)
If colLetter = "" Then colLetter = "D"
Dim lastValue As String
Dim hasHeader As Boolean
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim c As Range
Dim currentRow As Long
hasHeader = True 'Indicate true or false depending on if sheet  has header row.

If SavePath = "" Then SavePath = ThisWorkbook.Path
'Sort the workbook.
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range(colLetter & ":" & colLetter), _
    SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Sort
    .SetRange Cells
    If hasHeader Then ' Was a header indicated?
        .Header = xlYes
    Else
        .Header = xlNo
    End If
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With

For Each c In ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("D:D")
    If c.Value = "" Then Exit For
    If c.Row = 1 And hasHeader Then
    Else
        If lastValue <> c.Value Then
            If Not (wb Is Nothing) Then
                wb.SaveAs SavePath & "\" & lastValue & ".xls"
                wb.Close
            End If
            lastValue = c.Value
            currentRow = 1
            Set wb = Application.Workbooks.Add
        End If
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Rows(c.Row & ":" & c.Row).Copy
        wb.Sheets(1).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Select
        wb.Sheets(1).Paste

    End If
Next
If Not (wb Is Nothing) Then
    wb.SaveAs SavePath & "\" & lastValue & ".xls"
    wb.Close
End If
End Sub
```

This will generate a separate workbook in the same folder as the work book you run this from... or in the path you provide.

Comment: i dont seem to be able to get this code to work for come reason, @DanielCook would it be possible for me to send you an example of the file so you can see what i am up against?

Comment: Worked for me in Excel 2010, changed file extension to xlsx for both instances of xls. But to populate on the next empty row (otherwise it just overwrote the first record), I changed this line by adding Offset! ->  wb.Sheets(1).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Select